# getResponseBody(ClientHttpResponse) not quite working in DefaultResponseErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

`DefaultResponseErrorHandler` has some methods, but I would like to point out only a few of them. From source code:

```
    /**
     * Template method called from {@link #hasError(ClientHttpResponse)}.
     * <p>The default implementation checks {@link HttpStatusCode#isError()}.
     * Can be overridden in subclasses.
     * @param statusCode the HTTP status code
     * @return {@code true} if the response indicates an error; {@code false} otherwise
     * @see HttpStatusCode#isError()
     */
    protected boolean hasError(HttpStatusCode statusCode) {
        return statusCode.isError();
    }

    /**
     * Handle the error based on the resolved status code.
     *
     * <p>The default implementation delegates to
     * {@link HttpClientErrorException#create} for errors in the 4xx range, to
     * {@link HttpServerErrorException#create} for errors in the 5xx range,
     * or otherwise raises {@link UnknownHttpStatusCodeException}.
     * @since 5.0
     * @see HttpClientErrorException#create
     * @see HttpServerErrorException#create
     */
    protected void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response, HttpStatusCode statusCode) throws IOException {
        String statusText = response.getStatusText();
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        byte[] body = getResponseBody(response);
        Charset charset = getCharset(response);
        String message = getErrorMessage(statusCode.value(), statusText, body, charset);

        RestClientResponseException ex;
        if (statusCode.is4xxClientError()) {
            ex = HttpClientErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }
        else if (statusCode.is5xxServerError()) {
            ex = HttpServerErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }
        else {
            ex = new UnknownHttpStatusCodeException(message, statusCode.value(), statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.messageConverters)) {
            ex.setBodyConvertFunction(initBodyConvertFunction(response, body));
        }

        throw ex;
    }

    /**
     * Read the body of the given response (for inclusion in a status exception).
     * @param response the response to inspect
     * @return the response body as a byte array,
     * or an empty byte array if the body could not be read
     * @since 4.3.8
     */
    protected byte[] getResponseBody(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        try {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(response.getBody());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

The reason I created this thread is that I can't understand how the `getResponseBody` method works...

OK - to the point. I've extended this class to create my implementation of `ResponseErrorHandler` interface. Here it is:

```
public class RestTemplateErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    protected boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        getResponseBody(response);
        return super.hasError(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        String statusText = response.getStatusText();
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        byte[] body = "Dummy message".getBytes(); // <--- ONLY CHANGE COMPARING TO DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError
        Charset charset = getCharset(response);
        String message = getErrorMessage(statusCode.value(), statusText, body, charset);

        RestClientResponseException ex;
        if (statusCode.is4xxClientError()) {
            ex = HttpClientErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }
        else if (statusCode.is5xxServerError()) {
            ex = HttpServerErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }
        else {
            ex = new UnknownHttpStatusCodeException(message, statusCode.value(), statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.messageConverters)) {
            ex.setBodyConvertFunction(initBodyConvertFunction(response, body));
        }

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

As you noticed, I've only added `getResponseBody(response)` method call in overriden `hasError` and changed body in the handleError. When I make a `RestTemplate` call, it results in `StreamClosedException` of Apache HttpClient (under-the-hood HTTP client for `RestTemplate`).

I have no idea why that happens. Why `hasError` does not have an "access" to the `InputStream` of `response.getBody()`? Why is the stream closed there, but works perfectly fine in the **next** method? Also, in Spring Boot's source code we can also see:

```
    /**
     * Handle the given response, performing appropriate logging and
     * invoking the {@link ResponseErrorHandler} if necessary.
     * <p>Can be overridden in subclasses.
     * @param url the fully-expanded URL to connect to
     * @param method the HTTP method to execute (GET, POST, etc.)
     * @param response the resulting {@link ClientHttpResponse}
     * @throws IOException if propagated from {@link ResponseErrorHandler}
     * @since 4.1.6
     * @see #setErrorHandler
     */
    protected void handleResponse(URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = getErrorHandler();
        boolean hasError = errorHandler.hasError(response);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            try {
                HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
                logger.debug("Response " + statusCode);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.debug("Failed to obtain response status code", ex);
            }
        }
        if (hasError) {
            errorHandler.handleError(url, method, response);
        }
    }
```

`HasError` is the 1st method to be called, after the request has been made and response retrieved... and the stream is closed. But if the if statement `if(hasError)` is executed, then `handleErrors` *DO* have an access to the `getResponseBody`: stream is not closed and everything works fine. In both cases, it works on the same `ClientHttpResponse` object.

What's going on here?